# Android one line getText() declarations. What is the difference?

Tags: android, string

What is the difference? Aren't they actually the same thing?

I'm getting "Cannot resolve method 'getText' in 'View'"

`string = findViewById(R.id.signup_email).getText().toString();`

But it's working perfectly.

`textView = findViewById(R.id.signup_email);`

`string = textView.getText().toString();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `findViewById(R.id.signup_email)` returns the `View` object, so when you write this statement `findViewById(R.id.signup_email).getText()`  here `getText()`  applies on  `view` object (apparently `View` class does not contain this method).

But when you separate in two lines, here `textView = findViewById(R.id.signup_email);` the `View` object will be type cast to `TextView` or `EditText` (which you defined) object. so from here you will get this method.

If you want to keep in single line you can use

```
string = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.signup_email)).getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.signup_email)).getText().toString();
```

if you do just `findViewById` you will get `View` as the returned Object which is the parent of `TextView` but have a limited method to work with. So if we know what type of our view is we should cast the Object to the correct view intended So we can perform a variety of operation specific to that view.

In this case, it's `TextView` that is the reason we cast it to it and then we are able to use the `getText()` method of TextView Class which was not available in the `View` class hence you were getting compilation error for the usage of that method.

Comment: This is one of the right answer. It doesnot have explaination.

Comment: Thanks, @JinThakur. edited to add some explanation

Answer (score 0):

findViewById() returns a View. So the view does not heve getText() method. So if you modify the first option as follows:

```
string = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.signup_email)).getText().toString();
```

With this, it will cast view to TextView and than you can call get text method.